# Java If Else statement for abbreviations

Tags: java, if-statement

I've been working on this code, its really basic but I just started working with Java and I don't know whats going on with it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Proj {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Create Scanner
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Input Abbreviation
    System.err.print("Input METAR Abbreviation: "); 
    scanner.nextLine( );

    //Abbreviations
    String abb = "";
    if (abb.equals("B"))  {
        System.out.println ("Began At Time ");
    }
    else if(abb.equals("+")) {
        System.out.println ("Heavy intensity");
    }
    else if(abb.equals("-")) {
        System.out.println ("Light intensity");
    }
    else if(abb.equals("DZ")) {
        System.out.println ("Drizzle");
    }
    else if(abb.equals("E")) {
        System.out.println ("Ended At Time");
    }
    else if(abb.equals("HZ")) {
        System.out.println ("Haze");
    }
    else if(abb.equals("RA")) {
        System.out.println ("Rain");
    }
    else if(abb.equals("SN")) {
        System.out.println ("Snow");
    }
    else(abb !=NULL) {
        System.out.println("Unknown Abbreviation");
    }
    //Close scanner
    scanner.close( );
    }
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is when someone enters one of the abbreviations it prints out what it means, and if the abbreviation doesn't exist it prints out Unknown Abbreviation. 
So my problem is that when I run the code it prints Input METAR Abbreviation and you can enter a string but after that nothing happens, can someone help me out. Thanks

Comment: In Java 7+ you could replace this whole `if` `else` with switch case. Earlier versions support in switch only numbers and enums though. It's not the reason you don't receive data - that is explained by @Kakarot below.

Comment: Java `null` isn't `NULL`. You could load these into a `Map<String, String>` and return the value if it contains your key and the default otherwise.

Comment: You should consider using `equalsIgnoreCase()` or push the input to be uppercase to make the project more user-friendly. If I was expected to type in `DZ` I'd be pretty angry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `scanner.nextLine()` but never actually capture or use its result. Then, you assign `String abb= ""`. This means `abb` will always be `""`. That doesn't match any of your `if` conditions.

If you do `String abb = scanner.nextLine( );`, you'll get what you want: the scanner will read the next line, and assign that value to `abb`.

Incidentally, I doubt this code compiles; `NULL` isn't a keyword in Java (Java is case-sensitive), and the `else` needs an `if` after it. But you also don't need to check for `null`, because `scanner.nextLine()` never returns it (if there's no next line, it just throws `NoSuchElementException`). So the last bit should just be a plain `else {`.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems:

- You should assign the `scanner.nextLine()` result to a variable. In this case, I think you must assign it to `abb`:

  String abb = scanner.nextLine();
- Also, you forgot the `if` in the last condition:

  ```
  else if (abb != null) {
      System.out.println("Unknown Abbreviation");
  }
  ```
- And don't forget that Java is case-sensitive, so it must be `null`, not `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

May I sugest you use a switch statement, switch is much easier in your case instead of nested if, you can use

```
switch(condition){
case something:
//do stuff
}
```

For example

```
    switch(abb){
case "hello":
System.out.println("hi there")
break;
case "else string":
//do something 
break;
}
```

Good luck! Happy to help

Comment: Oh you are right, it's written by ipad (auto capitalization):D thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the line from Scanner but not storing it anywhere, change it as follows :

```
String abb = scanner.nextLine( );
```